# Android Parse Exception for certain locales

Tags: java, android, locale

I'm trying to format a date on Android but experiencing where I get an "Unparseable date" but only for certain Locales. Trying the same date for each Locale. Works fine in English but fails when I switch my device to DE for example.

Below is my code:

```
Locale locale = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
String dateStr = "07 Mar 2018";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", locale);
Date thedate = parser.parse(dateStr);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM", locale);
String dateStrReformatted = formatter.format(thedate);
```

I have tried specifying the current Locale but this has no effect. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The german locale string for `März` is `Mär` nor `Mar`

Comment: @Jens Thanks, cant believe I didn't realise that before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to parse `date` which is always in English as

```
String dateStr = "07 Mar 2018";
```

So while parsing you can use English as locale to get `date` and format it in your preferred language

```
String dateStr = "07 Mar 2018";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date englishDate = parser.parse(dateStr);
```

To get the local formatted `string` for above `date` use

```
Locale locale = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM", locale);
String dateStrReformatted = formatter.format(englishDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious now that you've pointed that out. My date is actually returned from a 3rd party api which is always in english, so I guess I will have to find another solution